# when to use multilevel index

Tags: database-design, indexing, schema

I am wondering in which situations is it best to use a multilevel index or any index, in terms of database systems. If I have the following schema as an example:

```
Course (course_code, course_name, course_leader)
Module (module_code, module_name, module_leader, semester)
Course_module (course_code, module_code)
Lecturer (employee_id, employee_name, email, phone)
```

assumptions can be made on the amount of rows and types of access. I just want to know when it is right to use a primary index instead of a multilevel or a secondary index etc.

Answer (score 1):

First a slight terminological clarification...

Primary index is simply an index under a primary key. Secondary index is any other index. So this is orthogonal to "simple" vs. "composite" (aka. "compound" or what you call "multilevel") index: primary index may or may not be composite and secondary index may or may not be composite.

---

To answer your question...

Depends on the database structure (PKs, FKs and clustering) and queries you intend to run.

For example, the database structure might imply:

- There will likely be a composite index on `Course_module {course_code, module_code}`, to support its PK.
- There will likely be an index on `Course_module {module_code}` to support the FK.
- If you wish to [cluster](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering) (aka. "index-organize") the courses based on `course_leader`, there will be a clustering index on `{course_leader}`<sup>1</sup>.
- Etc, etc...

The querying needs might imply:

- If you wish to find a course with given `course_name`, only and index on `{course_name}` is needed (for good performance).
- If you wish to find a course with given `course_name` and `course_leader` a composite index on `{course_name, course_leader}` is needed.
- If you wish to get courses that belong to the given `course_leader` you'll need an index on `{course_leader}`, but if your SELECT list contains only `course_name`, you might consider [covering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/covering-index) the query with the composite index `{course_leader, course_name}`.
- Etc, etc...

Each additional index lowers the performance of INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE so the index design is a balancing act between read and write performance.

All this stems from the structure of B-Trees and how they are used to satisfy various database operations. The complete treatment of this subject is really beyond the scope of any single StackOverflow answer, but if you are interested, i warmly recommend reading from start to finish: [Use The Index, Luke!](http://use-the-index-luke.com/)

---

<sup>1</sup> Some DBMSes don't support clustering at all, and most of those that do require the clustering key to equal the PK. MS SQL Server is a notable exception - you can cluster the data on a key different from PK.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it has pretty much cleared it up, one thing about composite indexes are they dissimilar to multilevel indexes 

http://people.cs.clemson.edu/~juan/CPSC862/Concept-31/Figure5.6.jpg

This is my interpretation of a multilevel index, a composite seems different

Comment: @user2358161 OK, this is a multi-level B-Tree. As somebody who accesses the DBMS from the "outside", you don't directly control how many levels will the B-Tree need to possess to store all the necessary values. The same index might be single-level B-Tree at one time and multi-level at another.